# DatePicker not showing

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I am trying to create a popup date picker from a button (the button that pops it up also shows the date). However the popup isn't showing. When the button is pressed nothing happens.

The DatePicker needs to be casted from an xml since I want it to show as spinners not a calendar (and from what I've read after API 21 the only way to do that is in xml)

Here is my code for the onClickLlistner for the button:

```
final Button startDate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startDate);
Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
mYear = currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
mMonth = currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int mDay = currentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

startDate.setText(mMonth + "/" + mDay + "/" + mYear);

startDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //get date from button text
            Calendar dateInButton = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
            try {
                dateInButton.setTime(sdf.parse(startDate.getText().toString()));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            int pYear = dateInButton.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int pMonth = dateInButton.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int pDay = dateInButton.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            //display popup datepicker
            final View dialogView = View.inflate(MyActivity.this, R.layout.date_picker, null);

            DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
            datePicker.updateDate(pYear, pMonth, pDay);
            datePicker.init(pYear, pMonth, pDay, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                    month++;
                    startDate.setText(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Comment: Better to used `DatePicker Dialog` then

Comment: Yes, from API 21, you can only able to see calendar view for datePicker, if you want view like previous versions of API, you need to create custom xml layout for that, and add it inside alert dialog.

Comment: Adding it inside an alert dialog worked. Thanks!